# Customize templates in a third party Django app

Tags: python, django

I'm using a third party app (django-social-share) in my Django project but I need to customize the templates.  I'm not sure how to go about doing that--everything I try keeps using the default templates.

The current default template is stored in:

```
django-social-share/django_social_share/templates/django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_facebook.html.
```

I've made my custom one in:

```
{{project_root}}/{{app_name}}/templates/django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_facebook.html
```

My templates setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'mainsite.context_processors.google_api'
            ],
            'loaders': (
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
            ),
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I do not understand at all how your question is not a duplicate of what you linked. Both have the same answer: either find a way to customize this in your own app without touching the 3rd-party lib, or fork the 3rd-party lib, make your changes, then use your fork.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how to do those things and I'm asking for assistance.  I forked the library but I don't know how to use my fork, and I don't know how to customize it within my own app.  How can I tell a third-party application to use my templates?

Comment: OK... well that's two completely separate questions. One (do it without changing 3rd party lib) cannot be answered so generally. We need to know what you're trying to do/change to know if it's possible to do it without modifying the 3rd-party lib. The other (how to fork a project on GitHub or elsewhere) I assume has been covered extensively on StackOverflow and elsewhere.

Comment: I've forked the project but I don't know how to make my own project use it (although I don't think that's the way to go for the relatively minor tweaks I need to do).  Ideally I'd like to just redirect the templates to my own modified ones.

Comment: Is your app listed before `django_social_share` in `INSTALLED_APPS`? The template loader will stop as soon as it encounters the first matching template path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the template in a separate app within your project. Django looks for templates in your apps in the order they are defined in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and uses the first match:

> The order of INSTALLED_APPS is significant! For example, if you want
>   to customize the Django admin, you might choose to override the
>   standard admin/base_site.html template, from django.contrib.admin,
>   with your own admin/base_site.html in myproject.polls. You must then
>   make sure that your myproject.polls comes before django.contrib.admin
>   in INSTALLED_APPS, otherwise django.contrib.admin’s will be loaded
>   first and yours will be ignored. ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader))

So create an app, called e.g. `social_share_templates`, and put it in `INSTALLED_APPS` *before* `django_social_share`. Then add the template to this folder:

```
{{project_root}}/social_share_templates/templates/django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_facebook.html
```

The reason your current configuration does not work, is that your local app has the same name as the app in site-packages. If your local app is an actual python module, you won't be able to use the app in site-packages. Otherwise, Django just looks for the templates in the app in site-packages.

Comment: The problem was the ordering of the apps.  Must've missed that in the docs.  Thank you!

Comment: I have tried this method and it is not working for me. I'm getting an error `ImportError: No module named social_share_templates`. Could this be because I'm using Wagtail?

Answer (score 5):

To just change templates you don't have to fork an app. Just make sure you have set up your template loaders correctly. Usually you'd like something as: ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#templates))

```
'loaders': [
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
],
```

This means (for your case take `django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_gplus.html` as an example) - when looking for the template Django will try to find it:

1. in your project's template directory/directories, specified in `DIRS`
   so if you have a file in `<project_root>/templates/django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_gplus.html`     it will take this one.
2. in your 'local' apps `templates` dir, if in `INSTALLED_APPS`. so you could create e.g. a `social_share_custom` app, add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` and create a template at:
   `<project_root>/social_share_custom/templates/django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_gplus.html`
   This approach has the benefit that you could re-use the `social_share_custom` easily in other projects.
3. in the `templates` directory of your apps installed via pip (or other ways)

Comment: Option 2 seems to be the way to go but I can't get it to work.  I've modified my question--any help?  I notice the documentation has revamped some of these things as of 1.8; not sure if that affects your answer.

Comment: what version of django are you using then?

Comment: I'm using Django v 1.9.6

Comment: in this case template settings are the same as for 1.8.*. is your custom app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Note that the `app_directories` loader loads from any app in `INSTALLED_APPS` that's not installed as an egg. It doesn't care about the actual location, as long as it's importable in python. `django_social_share` is installed as a usual python module, so the only thing that matters is the `DIRS` option and the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> Templates are in django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_twitter.html, 
>   django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_facebook.html and 
>   django_social_share/templatetags/post_to_gplus.html. You can override them 
>   to suit your mileage.

so you can override them directly.

If you want some tricky "override the the path where django looks for the template": 
First rename or move the original Template.
Then start django in debug mode browse to the place where the  - you should get the path - order where django tried to find the templates in the debug-screen.
Then try to place your templates before the original ones.

Or if you are experienced: 
Instantiate the app-Class, overwrite the template-files-location and use the new class.

Or symlink the original path or file to your new ones.