# Unable to override django template from 3rd party app

Tags: django, templates

I'm trying to override the base forum template for [django-machina](https://github.com/ellmetha/django-machina).

I've copied the `board_base.html` contents from [github source](https://github.com/ellmetha/django-machina/blob/master/machina/templates/machina/board_base.html) into  `/app/forum/templates/machina/board_base.html`.

My settings file contains a templates section like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
        ],
#snip
```

Django is definitely looking in that directory: if I set up a different view pointing to a nonexistent template file, then on the resulting error page the first path that Django reports trying is:

```
/app/forum/templates/nothing.html (Source does not exist)
```

What have I missed? Why can't I override that template?

---

Edit:

So my `DIRS` now looks like:

```
'DIRS': [
    MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
],
```

and I've got a separate app, `forum_templates`, with its own templates dir. `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'forum_templates',
    'core',

    # Machina related apps:
    'mptt',
    'haystack',
    'widget_tweaks',
] + get_machina_apps()
```

If I comment out the `MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR` from `DIRS`, I get the expected `TemplateDoesNotExist` error, with the following paths listed:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html
/app/forum/forum_templates/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html
/app/forum/core/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mptt/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/haystack/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/machina/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html
```

So I copy the relevant file from github and save it to `/app/forum/forum_templates/templates/partials/breadcrumb.html`; when I reload, the error moves onto the next template file.

If I then add `MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR` back into `DIRS`.. it starts loading all default templates out of machina again, ignoring the overrides in my `forum_templates` app.

What's going on? :(

Comment: may be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341254/customize-templates-in-a-third-party-django-app

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
from machina import MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (
            [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            MACHINA_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
            ),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                .... 
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now go to your base dir `/templates` and move the original Machina templates to this new place.  Be careful of the directory levels, you may have to experiment a bit.  Delete the origin Machina template dir so as to force it to find your new files.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may still comes across this, what I found a bit unclear in the [docs](https://django-machina.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/index.html#templates-and-static-files) regarding customizations, is that in order to override the templates, you should **NOT** add the `machina/` folder in your `templates/` directory. Instead, you should add the sub-apps folders directly e.g. `templates/forum/forum_detail.html` and **NOT** `templates/machina/forum/forum_detail.html`.

Overrides for the *base* files e.g. `board_base.html` should be placed in the root of your templates e.g. `templates/board_base.html`